# How to integrate Symfony 1.4 with Codeception

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony1, symfony-1.4, codeception

I want to be able to integrate Symfony 1.4 with Codeception unit tests.

I created init files but was unable to include Symfony library classes to be used for testing.

This page [Symfony 1.4 Unit testing](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/08?orm=Doctrine) explains a little but it doesn't show an example of instantiating a class even with Lime test. I tried this with Lime and it didn't work. Is there a way to auto include classes using Symfony Core which allows me to instantiate classes for my needs when creating unit tests?

I tried including unit.php file from Symfony test folder but got the same result of not being able to instantiate existing library classes.

If it is too hard to do it with Codeception then I'm looking for options in Lime test also. I just want to be able to unit test...

How would I do this?

Comment: Hey. Did you manage to marry symfony1.4 with codeception at the end? I would be very interested in some hints as I need to do this with a legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

Running these will load all your classes:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
sfCoreAutoload::register();
```

Of course you should set the paths properly.

You can also try to use the Symfony 1.5. maintained by L'express (https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1). It uses composer and have the autoloading prepared for you. (you just need to include `autoload.php`)